# Joining/merging hash tables c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am in .net 2.0 .
I am looking for a smart fast way to merge two hash tables. For now i am doing it like

```
foreach (string id in  _unValidatedMachine)
{
       _Machine.Add(id, _unValidatedMachine[id]);
} 


_unValidatedMachine.Clear();
```

I even not check here the inserted hash for existing of the key , probably i should do it .

Any ideas how to do the merge ?

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of key collisions?

Comment: @LukeH Not to add the problematic key.

Comment: When you say "hash tables", what class are you actually talking about? If it supports an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> then that will be faster than enumerating the keys and doing a lookup for each one.

Comment: @ Peter Taylor:I use Hashtable but I can change it for something faster .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a standard way to join two Hashtables.

Yes, you should check if the key is already added, in other case you could get an exception.

Also you could use:

```
_Machine[id] = _unValidatedMachine[id];
```

In this case, if the key exists, you will only overwrite its value.